# Testing Apps on Sony SmartEyeGlass Emulator

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

Friends,

I'm starting to develop for Sony SmartEyeGlass and I have some issues. To test an App I'm developing is needed to uninstall the SmartEyeGlass Emulator from my device every time? Is there another way to do this? It's possible to uninstall the app (not the emulator) via adb on the shell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set-up your testing environment only once. Make sure you have installed all 3 required apps: SmartConnect from google play, SmartEyeglass.apk and SmartEyeglassEmulator.apk. As described here: https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/get-started/#prepare-test-env

After that, you compile and install your SmartEyeglass application like a normal Android app. By running from your IDE or installing by adb. Also re-installing and removing is the same as with normal Android apps. You don't need to reinstall your emulator.

Let us know, if you have any problem.

Comment: Thanks teepee SONY. I was trying to reinstall from adb and it did not work, but via Eclipse worked.